# Azure pipeline - Execute one of the stages in a Container

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-tasks

Our Organization has started migrating to Azure.
We have Azure pipeline template which runs *checkout, build and deploy* stages on `vmImage: 'ubuntu-18.04'`.
Our plan is to introduce *"Test"* stage in the template and run tests in Container.

**Question:**

- When the entire pipeline is running on `vmImage`, is it possible to run one of the stages (Test) in Container?
- How to copy build artifacts from vmImage to run tests in Container?

Can someone please shed some light on this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi @Kevin Lu-MSFT, Thanks a lot for your response. 
I am trying out the solution that is recommended by you. I'll post as soon as I've update.

Comment: Hi @Yamuna. To follow up, could you please share the latest information with us? Feel free to let me know if the answer could work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When the entire pipeline is running on vmImage, is it possible to run one of the stages (Test) in Container?

In Azure Devops Yaml Pipeline, you could specify the `container` at the job level.

Then the job could run on the target container.

Here is [a doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops) about the detailed information.

> How to copy build artifacts from vmImage to run tests in Container?

In the previous stage, you could publish the build artifacts with the `Publish Build Artifacts task`.

In the stage (running job in the container), you could use the `Download Build Artifacts` task to download the artifacts to the container.

Finally, you could add the steps to test it.

Here is my sample:

```
resources:
  containers:
  - container: python
    image: python:3.8
trigger:
- none

   
stages:

  - stage: artifacts
    pool:
      vmimage:  ubuntu-latest
    jobs:
      - job: test123
        steps:
        - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
          inputs:
            PathtoPublish: '$(Build.Sourcesdirectory)'
            ArtifactName: 'drop'
            publishLocation: 'Container'
        - script: echo $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)

  - stage: testcontainer
    jobs:
      - job: test123
        container:  python
    
        steps:
        - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
          inputs:
            buildType: 'current'
            downloadType: 'single'
            artifactName: 'drop'
            downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'

        - script: |
            echo $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)
          displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```

**Note:** The container image is from Docker Hub,  Azure Container Registry or another private container registry.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Sorry for the delayed response. 
I've implemented it in a similar fashion. Instead of PublishBuildArtifacts@1 and  DownloadBuildArtifacts@0, I've used PublishPipelineArtifact@1 and DownloadPipelineArtifact@2